# Как занести начальные данные в таблицу, сразу после создания БД?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

я новичок в Node.js поэтому не судите строго. В ЯП ООП таком как С# после создания БД имеется возможность сразу добавить начальные значения в БД, за это отвечает функция HasData(). Вопрос, имеется ли подобная функция в Sequalize? Cпрашиваю, потому что не нашел информации об этом ни на англоязычных сайтах, ни на рускоязычных.
Если не существует такой функции, то как мне один раз добавить данные в БД, сразу после ее создания(не изменения)?

У меня имеется следующий код. Ниже демонстрируется самый главный файл (index.js) в котором я все подключаю все необходимые модули

```
...
const express = require("express");
const sequelize = require("./db");
const models = require("./models/models");
...

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await sequelize.sync();
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
start();
const defaultData = require("./models/DefaultData");  //Загружаю начальные данные
```

Самой последней строчкой я загружаю начальные данные в БД, однако это происходит не в момент создания БД, а сразу при запуске приложения, т.е. постоянно. Ниже демонстрируется содержимое файла DefaultData.

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const User = require("./User");
const Role = require("./Role");

const admin_id = uuidv4();
Role.create({ id: admin_id, name: "Admin" });
User.create({
  id: uuidv4(),
  name: "Admin",
  email: "admin@example.com",
  password: "admin",
  role_id: admin_id,
  is_locked: false,
});

const moderator_id = uuidv4();
Role.create({ id: moderator_id, name: "Moderator" });
User.create({
  id: uuidv4(),
  name: "Moderator",
  email: "moderator@example.com",
  password: "moderator",
  role_id: moderator_id,
  is_locked: false,
});

const user_id = uuidv4();
Role.create({ id: user_id, name: "User" });
User.create({
  id: uuidv4(),
  name: "User",
  email: "user@example.com",
  password: "user",
  role_id: user_id,
  is_locked: false,
});
```

Comment: C Sequalize не работал, однако опыт и здравый смысл подсказывает, что надо посчитать количество записей в таблицах и если там 0 записей, то добавлять. И еще это очень плохой вариант при каждом старте приложения проверять и создавать начальную структуру БД. Установка приложения и создание начальной БД должно быть вынесено в отдельный этап жизненного цикла ПО(т.е. в отедельный установочный скрипт), а сам приклад должен запускаться и работать(возможно проверяя, что есть данные для работы)

Comment: @Swad, благодарю